# Returning middle value in each category

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried every way I could think of but no success. From the following dataset, I would like to get these results. Any guidance and help would be greatly appreciated!

desired result

```
Name            Category    Quantity    Price    
Product A       Sports        80         30
Product B       Finance       90         60
```

dataset

```
Name            Category    Quantity    Price    
Product A       Sports        80         30
Product B       Finance       90         60        
Product C       Sports        70         70
Product D       Finance       30         100
Product E       Finance       100        80
Product F       Sports        90         60
```

Comment: Do you only ever have 3 entries per category? if no, what if there are more? And what if the number of entries is even?

Comment: Are you permitted to sort the dataset by category?

Comment: @ScottCraner typo on my side, thank you!

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Total number of entries is different for each category. Would it change anything? They are never even, all have different values.

Comment: @xidgel Thats how I do it now, but I'm trying to put a formula in place so that I would not have to sort it everytime.

Comment: While formulas can certainly do this, vba or power query would be better tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. I have your data set as an Excel table named `Table1` and your desired results located with the header starting at `A1` and the results starting at `A2`.

To get the median Quantity for Category `Sports` in cell `B2` put this formula in `C2`:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(Table1[Category]=B2,Table1[Quantity],""))
```

entered as an array formula <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To get the corresponding Name in `A2`, concatenate the Category and Quantity values and use that as a lookup value for a (virtual) column made by concatenating the Category and Quantity columns. Use `MATCH` to do the lookup and `INDEX` to find the corresponding name:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Name],MATCH(B2&TEXT(C2,"0"),Table1[Category]&TEXT(Table1[Quantity],"0"),0))
```

entered as an array formula <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use the same technique to get the corresponding Price:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Price],MATCH(B2&TEXT(C2,"0"),Table1[Category]&TEXT(Table1[Quantity],"0"),0))
```

Then copy down to rows 3, 4, ...

Hope that helps